# I want both values before and after submitting a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple form and inside there are two input fields text type. 
for example if input has initially value like "Hello" and later on I have changed it to "Hi" and then I submit this form.

I want to see this both values, anyone suggest me please

markup

```
    <form action="index_submit" method="get" name="anil" > 
        <label for="first_name">first name</label><input type="text" name="first_name" value="" id="first_name">
        <label for="last_name">last name</label><input type="text" name="last_name" value="" id="last_name">
        <label for="user_name">user name</label><input type="text" name="user_name" value="" id="user_name">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="reset" id="reset">
    </form>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('form #submit').click(function(){
        var oldValue
        var newValue
    });   
})
```

Comment: Show some HTML and javascript please.  JSFiddle.net is your friend when asking for help.

Comment: You should definitely show us what you've tried. Note, too, that depending on what your back end is, it might be simpler to handle it there.

Comment: What is your server side language? You'd better handle this on the server.

Comment: I just started coding Js part but want to have some idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the initial value in a hidden field as well as the visible one, e.g.:

```
<input type="text" name="greeting" value="Hello" />
<input type="hidden" name="greeting-original" value="Hello" />
```

Then you can do what you like with `greeting` and `greeting-original` when the form is submitted.

Comment: what about if the values get change next time?

Comment: by the way good idea I should work on it. Thanks for showing me light, I should swap values between hidden and visible inputs after each submit event, will accept you answer :)